# Update Columns of Table with First value of objects

Tags: php, json

I Have a json Array, And This is one row of my json Rows, How Can I Put `38` to `id38` Column and `39` to `id39` Column.. Automaticaly?
[image: Please see This Photo]

This is My Code:

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","array");
mysqli_set_charset($con,"utf8");
if (mysqli_connect_errno()){
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }
$sql="SELECT `survey_answers`,us_id FROM `user_survey`";
if ($result=mysqli_query($con,$sql)){
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)){
        $json = $row[0];
        if(!is_null($json)){                           
        //$json = preg_replace("!\r?\n!", "", $json);
        $jason_array = json_decode($json,true);
            $id = array();
            foreach ($jason_array as $data) {
            if (array_key_exists('id', $data)) {
            $id[] = $data['id'];
            }
            }
             $ids= implode(', \r\n',$id); 
            $sql1="update user_survey set id38='$ids' where us_id=".$row[1];
            echo $sql1."<br>";
            mysqli_query($con,$sql1);
        }
    }
}
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to do something like this:

```
     <?php
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)){
        $json = $row[0];
        if(!is_null($json)){                
    $jason_array = json_decode($json,true);
    $idv=array();
    foreach ($jason_array as $data) {

        if (array_key_exists('id', $data)) {
            $id =$data['id'];
            $idv[] = "id$id='$id'";
        }
    }
    $ids= implode(',',$idv);
    $sql1="update user_survey set $ids where us_id=".$row[1];
    echo $sql1."<br>";
    mysqli_query($con,$sql1);// run the sql
        }
}
```

[DEMO](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/d36b8e8a06fe76f6664f42e78cc3e54c4af77289)

Comment: in echo is okey, But I Can't get output in mysql  `update user_survey set id38='38',id39='39' where condition`

Comment: I Mean in PHPmyadmin id38 Column There isn't anything

Comment: @SedricHeidarizarei does your sql shows any error. run the sql directly in phpmyadmin and see.

Comment: I Don't Have Any Error In My explorer, `update user_survey set id38='38',id39='39' where condition
update user_survey set id38='38',id39='39' where condition`, How Should U Run Sql Directly, I'm New in programing

Comment: I Pasted Your Code, But I Got unexpected charakter, red circle for all lines

Comment: @SedricHeidarizarei red circle means some syntax error check for your code part if any syntax wrong.The above code is syntactically correct.What is your editor.

Comment: Solved, With Your Update, Appriciate it @Suchit kumar

Comment: I'm Using notepad++  because of utf8 Support

Comment: @SedricHeidarizarei for your note don't leave your questions open, meaning once you got the right answer accept the answer so it will marked the question close and help other user.I'm talking about the similar question your have posted earlier.

Comment: Okey, I Will Click in Green Tick Button,

Comment: @SedricHeidarizarei only if it helped you. Do not mark unnecessarily instead delete that question if it is duplicate.wrong marking will lead later user to wrong path.

Comment: Okey, Sure, ...  +1